# Deploying my APP which keeps requesting ggplot2

Tags: shiny

I am trying to deploy this app but I keep getting the following error message:

```
    * Application depends on package "ggplot2" but it is not installed.
       Please resolve before continuing.
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
      Failed to infer source for package 'ggplot2'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
    2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
      Failed to infer source for package 'ggplot2'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
    3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
      Failed to infer source for package 'ggplot2'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
    4: Unable to package DESCRIPTION files: Couldn't find DESCRIPTION file for ggplot2 
    Execution halted
```

I have tried many times to install the ggplot2 package to no avail

What do I do? Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
ui<-fluidPage(
  theme=shinytheme("sandstone"),
  h2(titlePanel("Descriptive Data")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("radio","Select Dataset",choices=c(
        "People",
        "Industries",
        "Schools",
        "Hospitals"
      ),select="People"),
      fileInput("file","Upload Dataset",placeholder="No file selected"),
      sliderInput("slider","Pie Chart Angle",min=45,max=405,value=45,step=5),
      selectInput("xAxis","Select X variable",choices=c(
        "People",
        "Industries",
        "Schools",
        "Hospitals"
      ),selected="People"),
      selectInput("yAxis","Select Y variable",choices=c(
        "People",
        "Industries",
        "Schools",
        "Hospitals"
      ),selected="Industries"),
      sliderInput("point","Point Size",min=1,max=10,value=3,step=1),
      textAreaInput("text","Research Observation"),actionButton("action","Post Observation")


    ),

    mainPanel(strong(h2("Choose How Data is Displayed",style="color:#5dade2")),
              tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel(h4("Histogram",style="color:#3498db"),selectInput("col","Change Graph Colour",choices=c(
                  "Red",
                  "Blue",
                  "Green",
                  "Yellow",
                  "Orange",
                  "Purple"
                ),selected="Blue"),plotOutput("histo",height=500,width=550)),
                tabPanel(h4("Bar Plot",style="color:green"),selectInput("colo","Change Graph Colour",choices=c(
                  "Red",
                  "Blue",
                  "Green",
                  "Yellow",
                  "Orange",
                  "Purple"
                ),selected="Green"),plotOutput("Bar",height=500,width=550)),
                tabPanel(h4("Pie Chart",style="color:red"),plotOutput("Pie",height=500,width=600)),
                tabPanel(h4("Scatter Plot",style="color:#f39c12"),selectInput("scolo","Change Point Colour",choices=c(
                  "Red",
                  "Blue",
                  "Green",
                  "Yellow",
                  "Orange",
                  "Purple"
                ),selected="Blue"),plotOutput("Scatter",height=500,width=550)),
                tabPanel(h4("Box Plot",style="color:#8e44ad"),selectInput("colos","Change Graph Colour",choices=c(
                  "Red",
                  "Blue",
                  "Green",
                  "Yellow",
                  "Orange",
                  "Purple"
                ),selected="Purple"),plotOutput("Box",height=500,width=550)),
                tabPanel(h4("Table",style="color:brown"),DTOutput("Tab",width="100%",height="100%")),
                tabPanel(h4("Observations",style="color:black"),textOutput("txt"))


              )
    )))

server<-function(input,output,session){

  output$histo<-renderPlot({
    data<-switch(input$radio,
                 "People"=people,
                 "Industries"=industries,
                 "Schools"=schools,
                 "Hospitals"=hospitals)
    color<-switch(input$col,
                  "Red"=red,
                  "Blue"=blue,
                  "Green"=green,
                  "Yellow"=yellow,
                  "Orange"=orange,
                  "Purple"=purple)

    hist(data,col=color,main="Histogram",xlab="Dataset",
         ylab="Values",border="white")

  })

  output$Bar<-renderPlot({
    data<-switch(input$radio,
                 "People"=people,
                 "Industries"=industries,
                 "Schools"=schools,
                 "Hospitals"=hospitals)
    colors=switch(input$colo,
                  "Red"=red,
                  "Blue"=blue,
                  "Green"=green,
                  "Yellow"=yellow,
                  "Orange"=orange,
                  "Purple"=purple)

    barplot(data,col=colors,border="white",xlab="Dataset",
            ylab="Values",main="Bar Plot")
  }) 

  output$Pie<-renderPlot({

    prop<-c(
      "People"=people.prop,
      "Industries"=industries.prop,
      "Schools"=schools.prop,
      "Hospitals"=hospitals.prop)

    pie(prop,init.angle=input$slider,radius=1.1,clockwise=TRUE,col=c(4:7),
        labels=c("People","Industries","Schools","Hospitals"),border="white")
    legend("topright",legend=prop,fill=c(col=c(4:7)),cex=1,
           box.lty=1,box.lwd=2,text.font=2,inset=.02)

  })
  output$Box<-renderPlot({
    data<-switch(input$radio,
                 "People"=people,
                 "Industries"=industries,
                 "Schools"=schools,
                 "Hospitals"=hospitals)
    colorly=switch(input$colos,
                   "Red"=red,
                   "Blue"=blue,
                   "Green"=green,
                   "Yellow"=yellow,
                   "Orange"=orange,
                   "Purple"=purple)

    boxplot(data,col=colorly)

  })
  output$Scatter<-renderPlot({
    variable<-switch(input$xAxis,
                     "People"=people,
                     "Industries"=industries,
                     "Schools"=schools,
                     "Hospitals"=hospitals)

    variables<-switch(input$yAxis,
                      "People"=people,
                      "Industries"=industries,
                      "Schools"=schools,
                      "Hospitals"=hospitals)
    colory=switch(input$scolo,
                  "Red"=reds,
                  "Blue"=blues,
                  "Green"=greens,
                  "Yellow"=yellows,
                  "Orange"=oranges,
                  "Purple"=purples)

    plot(variable,variables,xlab="X Variable",ylab="Y Variable",
         main="Scatter Plot Diagram",col=colory,pch=16,type="p",
         cex=input$point)

  })
  output$Tab<-renderDT({
    data.frame(
      "People"=people,
      "Industries"=industries,
      "Schools"=schools,
      "Hospitals"=hospitals)
  })
  output$txt<-renderText({
    input$action
    isolate(paste(input$text))
  })
}

people=c(5,15,60,66,70,15,8,9,23,40,40,8,15,7,6)
industries=c(33,20,87,60,34,42,71,10,54,12,33,45,17,45,90)
schools=c(21,45,65,87,32,97,21,33,55,41,57,23,82,14,53)
hospitals=c(10,24,54,71,82,64,53,23,14,72,18,16,32,23,15)

red="#e74c3c"
blue="#3498db"
green="#2ecc71"
yellow="#f1c40f"
orange="#e67e22"
purple="#8e44ad"

reds="red"
blues="blue"
greens="green"
yellows="yellow"
oranges="orange"
purples="purple"
people.prop=0.5
industries.prop=0.35
schools.prop=0.10
hospitals.prop=0.05

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Does this mean the application runs fine locally, but you get this error only on `shinyapps.io`? Have you tried adding `library(ggplot2)` to the script?

Comment: Yes the application runs locally. I have tried adding library(ggplot2) to the script but I get the same result. I have installed the ggplot2 package many times but I can't seem to load it, and this is stopping my app from deploying on shinyapps.io